# undefined reference to `json_tokener_parse'

Tags: c, openwrt, json-c

all.

I'm having trouble using the [JSON-C](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) library on an OpenWRT linux distribution.
I made a simple program below in order to test it.

```
#include <json/json.h>

int main() {
    char * string = "{\"name\" : \"joys of programming\"}";
    json_object * jobj = json_tokener_parse(string);
}
```

I then compile it with the following command.

```
gcc test.c -o test -ljson-c
```

However, I get the following errors.

```
In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `json_tokener_parse'
test.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `json_tokener_parse'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I even compiled it with the command below, but it still didn't work.

```
gcc -ljson-c test.c -o test
```

I then tried to add the -L parameter when compiling, but still no luck.

```
gcc test.c -o test -L/usr/lib -ljson-c
```

This OpenWRT distribution uses **opkg** as its package installer, and here's what displays when I run **opkg install libjson-c**.

```
Package libjson-c (0.11-2) installed in root is up to date.
```

I even ran the compile command with the -E parameter to see if the correct header is being used, and it seems like it is as I can find the method declaration **json_tokener_parse**. I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong. I'm about to do a manual installation from Github, but I don't really want to do that because I would have to manually install other programs as well. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you included `json_tokener.h`?

Comment: @Pushkin I tried it, but this doesn't work either. Also, after using the -E parameter, the header file is being brought it correctly with the json.h header.

Comment: Make sure that the `json_tokener_parse` symbol is defined in `/usr/lib/libjson-c.{a,so}`.  You can do this by using the `nm` command tool, if it exists on your platform.

Comment: @JeremyRodi I ran the command on the .so file, and it says **no symbols**. I'm guessing that's my problem? lol. Does this mean my installed version is just bad? Would I have to get another version?

Comment: `undefined reference` is a linker error, not a compiler error. There is no point in thinking that the problem is with header file. `nm` might not always work as the symbols might be stripped even though your library is defining the function. Can you google if `libjson-c` is actually defining `json_tokener_parse` .

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem myself and if you explicitly link the libraries it will compile and link: `gcc -g -v -Wall -std=gnu99 -static -L/path/to/json-c-0.9/lib main.c -o test1 -ljson`